# undefined method 'model_name' for class_name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to grab a user job notes but am not sure what I am doing wrong. At first I was able to get the job and note working properly when I nested just the two but when I wanted to get the user job notes then my code broke.

**notes.controller new**

```
def new
  @note = @user_note.notes.new
end

private 

def user_note
    @user = current_user
    @job = @user.job.find(params[:job_id])
end
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :jobs
has_many :notes, through: :jobs
```

**job.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :note
```

**notes.rb**

```
has_many :jobs
has_many :users, through: :jobs
```

In rails console if I were to type the following code it works fine.

```
User.last.jobs
```

If I were to try to code below it does not

```
User.last.jobs.notes
```

then I get the error

```
undefined method `notes' for #<Job:0x007fe37dc77190>
```

How can I properly grab the user_id when creating a note for a job? right now it grabs the job id for the note but does not grab the user id. I would like to be able to find notes from a job and user. Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic fault is that you are asking through 2 has_many relations. This is not possible. You could do something like:

```
user = User.last
user.jobs  # returns all the user's jobs
user.notes # returns all the user's notes
user.jobs.each_with_object({}) {|job, hash| hash[:job.id] = job.note_ids]} 
  # returns a hash with user's job_id as keys and an array of related note_ids as value
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `has_many :through`, you should just use:

`User.last.notes`

This will get the last user's notes through jobs

Answer (score 0):

your notes model looks like it has a typo, should be

```
has_many :jobs
```

instead of

```
has_jobs
```